# How to keep horizontal scroll position of jqGrid while inline-editing?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid table on my page, with lots of columns, so the grid is wider than browser window, horizontal scrollbar appears.

The problem is, that when user clicks on a row to begin editing, browser frame is scrolled to the left, thus confusing the user and even sometimes hiding the choosen cell.

I've tried the methods which i've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706703/how-to-reload-jquery-grid-keeping-scroll-position-and-collapse-elements-open) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/inline-edit-problem-with-scrolling/), but they don't work for me - i can retreive current scroll position, but i can't set it.
Cells are set as editable in columnsModel, so i get scroll position at formatCell event and try to set scroll position at afterEditCell with the following code:

```
afterEditCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, irow, icol) { 

 jQuery("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft(scrollPosition);
 window.scrollTo(scrollPosition,0);
 if (window.pageXOffset) {window.pageXOffset = scrollPosition;};
 if (document.body.parentElement) {document.body.parentElement.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;};   
 if (document.body) {document.body.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;};
```

And, this does not affect anyhow the behavior of grid - it scrolls to the most left position.

Are there any other ways to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

try this one on loadComplete function

```
var offset = $("#" + *subgrid_table_id*).offset();
var w = $(window);
var fromTop = offset.top - w.scrollTop();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset.top - fromTop
}, 1);
```

this code keep the last position of grid

Answer (score 0):

move scrolling code inside setTimeout() like:

setTimeout(function(){ 
    grid2.closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft(scrollPosition);
                           },100);

Answer (score 0):

@Andrus - why to timeout? Anyway I implemented your code to my solution.

Inline editing from jqgrid page:

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
    if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
        jQuery('#grid_id').restoreRow(lastSel); 
        lastSel=id; 
    }
    jQuery('#grid_id').editRow(id, true); 
},
```

My version with scrolling which doesn't "jump" to left:

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
    scrollPosition = jQuery('#grid_id').closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft();
    if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
        jQuery('#grid_id').restoreRow(lastSel); 
        lastSel=id; 
    }
    jQuery('#grid_id').editRow(id, true).scrollLeft(scrollPosition); 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid, status, e){
  if (lastID) grid.jqGrid("restoreRow", lastID);

  if (rowid !== lastID) {
    var scrollPosition = grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft();

    grid.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, false, function(){
      setTimeout(function(){ $("input, select", e.target).focus(); }, 10);
    });

    setTimeout(function(){ grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft(scrollPosition); }, 0);

    lastID = rowid;
  }
  else lastID = null;
}
```