# How to keep vertical scroll position of jqGrid while trigger reloadGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reload JQuery grid keeping scroll position and collapse elements open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706703/how-to-reload-jquery-grid-keeping-scroll-position-and-collapse-elements-open)

The jqGrid will scroll top when trigger reloadGrid.

Is there a option of JqGrid or any idea to keep the vertical scroll position of jqGrid while trigger reloadGrid?

Many thanks!